# Actualizar gridview despues de seleccionar un item del mismo

Tags: android, gridview

Hola amigos me gustaria que me ayuden a actualizar un gridview despues de selecionar uno se sus item, osea dentro del evento onItemClickListener o si hay otra forma pero que se actualize despues de seleccionar un item del grid.

Les muestro algo del codigo

```
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.juegodeletra);


    adaptadorimagenjuego adap = new adaptadorimagenjuego(this, nu());
    barra = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid1);
    gridView.setAdapter(adap);

    muss();
    alertas();



    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(dato==position){


            }
            else{

            }

        }
    });
```

quiero que en el metodo onItemClick si se cumple la condicion se Actualize mi gridview, agradeceria cualquier aporte  amigos

Comment: Una pregunta, ese nu() es una funcion que te devuelve una lista???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente llama el método [invalidateViews()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) para actualizar tu GridView.

```
gridview.InvalidateViews();
```

Si usas un Adapter, también puedes actualizarlo mediante la ejecución de [notifyDatasetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html):

```
gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataChanged();
```

Comment: Muy buen aporte. Eficiente y sencillo para actualizar los datos de un gridview.